# Undefined mixin after upgrading to most recent versions of Sass, Compass, Breakpoint-Sass and Toolkit-Sass

Tags: sass, breakpoint-sass

After upgrading today to the most recent versions of Sass, Compass, Breakpoint-Sass and Toolkit-Sass I get for every mixin used im my theme an undefined mixin error.

my current gemfile includes these version:


`gem 'compass-aurora',     '~>3.0.8'

gem 'toolkit',            '~>2.0.0.alpha.3'

gem 'breakpoint',         '~>2.4.1'`

after doing again a `bundle install` toolkit version 2.0.0.alpha.5 got installed.
 Might there be going on something and do I have to be a bit more patient? I know, toolkit is in alpha state ...

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Just to be clear, the exact same code worked prior to upgrading?  Have you checked those projects to see if there is an upper version limit on the Sass or Compass dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Compass Aurora isn't yet compatible with with all of the new goodies in Toolkit and Breakpoint. When it is, the gem will be updated.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Because I couldn't find a dependency from Compass Aurora I was curious what might cause this. Thanks for your efforts!